# off() & on() remove specific previous delegated event

Tags: jquery

I have this `off()` then `on()` combo to prevent my ajax from multiple sending:

```
$('#selector #selector_form').off("submit").on("submit", function(e) {
    // some ajax functions here
});
```

Now I want to apply what is said on the documentation of `off()` regarding the **"Remove just one previously bound handler by passing it as the third argument"**.

I rewrite my code to something like this:

```
function testtest(e) {
    // relocated ajax functions here
}

$('#selector #selector_form').off("submit", testtest).on("submit", testtest);
```

Now my AJAX returns to the behavior of having multiple sending. What I am missing?

Comment: Your first one wasn't preventing multiple sends either.  Calling `.off()` immediately followed by `.on()` just doesn't do anything.  You remove it, then put it right back before anything else has happened.  Now if you removed it when the event was fired and didn't put it back until sometime later when the ajax call had completed or when some other async operation had been completed, then it would do something interesting, but as you show it, neither accomplishes much of anything.

Comment: It does in my case because this `$('#selector #selector_form').off("submit").on("submit", function(e) {});` is inside a `live()`. I know it is deprecated, but what can I do, it is what's done here already.

Comment: use event namespacing... `$('#selector #selector_form').off("submit.someevent").on("submit.someevent", testtest);`

Comment: the root cause can be the `testtest` reference may not be a shared one

Comment: Why not use `$.one()`? http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: If somehow this all being inside a `.live()` handler is at all relevant here, then you aren't showing us the more interesting part of the problem and thus we can't offer the more interesting part of an answer.

Comment: Oh, and as for `.live()`, there's plenty you can do.  You can change it to use the dynamic form of `.on()` so you won't be forever stuck on a really old version of jQuery that deprecated `.live()` for good reasons.

Comment: @ArunPJohny - What do you mean by this "the root cause can be the testtest reference may not be a shared one"?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unclear what are you doing here but probably the following way you want to do:

```
$('#selector #selector_form').on("submit.tests", function(e){
  testtest();
  $(this).off("submit.tests");
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Where did that `.tests` come from?

Comment: that's the use of namespace.

Comment: But why .tests? Should I substitute it with something? Where is my reference for that?

Comment: Will it not conflict/collide a class name? Will it ensure that it will not remove other delegated event (in case I have multiple) in `#selector #selector_form`?

Comment: That's why we use namespace refer this link: http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace

Comment: I have a `data : $(this).serializeArray(),` inside testtest(), I tried to `console.log()` it and it doesn't have any value. How can I pass the selector to the function?